# Minitest should_not_receive rspec equivalent

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a list of objects, and want to see that some receive a call to a certain method while the others don't.

I'm interested in doing this without adding any extra testing dependencies (so no mocha or any other mocking/stubbing framework).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your test and mock a you normally do, and then wrap your `verify` method call in an `assert_raises`.

```
@mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
@mock.expect :update, true
Foo.do_something @mock
assert_raises(MockExpectationError, "update should not be called") do
  @mock.verify
end
```